# XNA Game Studio - Cannot edit files in project

Tags: c#, xna

I am using an **XNA Game 4.0** project in Visual Studio 2017, and am having problems with editing a file within a folder.

I have a file called `debuglog.txt` in a folder called `Logs`.

The folder and file were added to the project properly; they both appear in the `bin/x68/Debug` directory correctly (`debuglog.txt` is in `Logs`, and `Logs` is in `bin/x68/Debug`).

However, when I try to edit the contents of the file in the `LoadContent` method like so:

```
public string fileName = @"Content\Logs\debuglog.txt";
...
protected override void LoadContent(){
    //Only the relevant code is shown and this is guaranteed to run
    using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))){
        writer.Write("Test");
    }
}
```

the file does not have "Test" in it.

I tried to leave out the `Content` part of the file path, but it didn't work then either.

**Q:**  Why is the file not being written to?

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting any exceptions? Then I would suspect the relative path writing to another position. Do you have any other 'debuglog.txt' on the disk?
Try setting a break-point on writer.Write and check value for stream/Name. Is it pointing to the correct path?

Comment: no exceptions are being thrown/caught and there are no other `debuglog.txt` files on the disk; any extras have been deleted.  i'll check the stream/Name when i get access to my computer later today.

Comment: I some research, and it turns out that I didn't even load the file from the pipeline.  The path was correct.  Thanks anyway